# Draw parallel edges in jsnetworkx

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, networkx, jsnetworkx

I have a multigraph, and I would like to be able to see each edge that goes from one vertex to another clearly. For example, when I have a graph with 2 vertices, and 3 edges going from the first to the second, but i only see one edge. I'm using the jsnetworkx api

```
var G = new jsnx.MultiGraph();
        G.addNodesFrom([0,1]);
        G.addEdgesFrom([[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]);
        var color = d3.scale.category20();
        jsnx.draw(G, {
            element: '#canvas',
            layoutAttr: {
                charge: -120,
                linkDistance: 100
            },
            nodeAttr: {
                r: 10,
                title: function(d) { return d.label;}
            },
            nodeStyle: {
                fill: function(d) {
                return color(d.data.group);
                },
                stroke: 'none'
            },
            edgeStyle: {
                fill: '#999',
                'stroke-width':10
            },
            stickyDrag: true
        });
```

This is what i get as a result :
[Two node example network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7L9v.png)

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

`JSNetworkX > jsnx.draw(...)` offers a (descriptive) API implemented by some d3.js coding ...

- but I think there is no appropriate `JSNetworkX` API solution for your "parallel edges" problem.

You have to do the drawing by yourself, i.e. by implementing draw(G) per d3js code ...

See:

```
https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/raw/aaa995cde6621745e906/
```

> by E.Meeks for further "drawing edges" investigations,
>   especially the "offset edge type" ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18943393)

Comment: @Zze
Generally you're right, thanks for your edits.

But development on https://github.com/fkling/JSNetworkX
is frozen since 19 Jul 2015,
and JSNetworkX relays upon old-fashioned v3-Version of d3.js
so I decided to only give a hint so far ...

If the question opener is further involved in this topic,
then he could do the workout of the "essential part out my answer"
and report it here ...